# Error message using model parameter in Translate API

Tags: api, cloud, translate

I tried to use the Cloud Translation API Premium Beta edition. I build a small sample java application using the parameter model

```
( 
...
TranslateOption model = TranslateOption.model("nmt");
Translation translation = translate.translate(text, srcLang, tgtLang, model);
...
).
```

I get an error message

```
Exception in thread "main" com.google.cloud.translate.TranslateException: Invalid JSON payload received. Unknown name "model": Cannot bind 'nmt'
```

Does anyone know, what's wrong?